# Dell iDRAC: the difference between "Embedded OS deployment tools" and "Remote OS deployment"

Tags: server, operating-system, installation, ubuntu-server, headless

I'm considering getting a collection of Dell PowerEdge servers. Dell documentation is pretty poor (no surprise there) and I have trouble figuring out if I can go with iDRAC Basic or if I need iDRAC Express or Enterprise.

My need is to install Ubuntu Server (minimal install with SSH is enough). After install all I need is SSH and possibly a remote "reset" button. I can install the OS before taking the system to server room so I don't really need remote OS deployment tools. However, the server does not have a graphics adapter. Is it possible to install Ubuntu with just iDRAC Basic or do I need additional hardware?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#iwork4dell Remote OS deployment implies Virtual Console (like VNC) and Virtual Media (using a remote ISO like a local DVD).  These are Enterprise license features.  OS deployment tools are are the driver pack that is stored in flash on the server and made available during OS installation to support new hardware on older OSes.

The iDRAC is an integrated VGA adapter so all the Power Edge servers do have a video adapter in them unless you disable it in BIOS.  If your willing to attach a keyboard and monitor to the server basic is all you need.  You can also upgrade the iDRAC with a license key after purchase.

See http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/extras/m/white_papers/20440743
and http://i.dell.com/sites/doccontent/shared-content/data-sheets/en/Documents/idrac-spec-sheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

IDRAC is possible, just you can open gui of idrac and then launch on the online server. You can add the iso file on virtual server.

Comment: I know that iDRAC *Enterprise* supports mounting remote iso images and booting from those. As far as I know, you cannot do this with iDRAC *Express* or iDRAC *Basic* licenses. I would like to be proven incorrect.